# Matplotlib: imshow gives values outside of extent (Bug?)

Tags: matplotlib, coordinates, python-3.7, imshow, extent

With this code you can produce such an image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

axes = plt.subplot()
axes.set_aspect(1)
axes.format_coord = "x={:1.2f}, y={:1.2f}".format

pltRange = range(-1, 12)
axes.set_xlim(min(pltRange), max(pltRange))
axes.set_ylim(min(pltRange), max(pltRange))
axes.set_xticks(pltRange)
axes.set_yticks(pltRange)
plt.grid(True)

array = np.random.random((10, 10))
image = axes.imshow(array, extent=[0, 10, 0, 10], origin='lower')
image.format_cursor_data = " |  Value: {:8f}".format

plt.show()
```

[image]

On the bottom right you can see the coordinates of the mouse cursor and the value of the array you are moving over.
This works fine on the coloured tiles. But I also expect to get no value when I move my mouse over the white plates.

On the top and on the right side, this does happen. But not on the bottom and on the left.
If you move your mouse to the position, lets say `(-0.5, 2.5)`, you will still get a value. That makes no sense to me.

Am I doing something wrong or is that a bug? I am using Matplotlib 3.0.3. and Numpy 1.16.2.

Thank you :)

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in the current development version. There will be a release of matplotlib 3.1 soonish. In any case the observed behaviour is not detrimental, you just see the value of the neighboring pixel when moving the mouse outside and to the left and/or bottom. The values inside are correct.

Comment: So it is really a bug :O